# JavaFX, Can you bind property of an moving circle?

Tags: java, binding, properties, javafx, geometry

So i got one moving circle on a timeline. And im trying to bind it to the screen so when i rezise the screen on the app, i want the ball to scale instead of moving outside the screen. Is that possible?

```
        circle.centerXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2));
        circle.centerYProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().divide(2));         
        circle.radiusProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2));
```

This is the code i have tried for using it doesnt work.

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't too useful for anyone trying to help here. Can you create a simple, executable example (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance) and edit your question to include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind the radius property of the circle to the minimum of the width and the heights properties to keep the circle radius inside the pane:

```
circle.radiusProperty().bind(Bindings.min(pane.widthProperty().divide(2),
                                          pane.heightProperty().divide(2)));
```

Comment: i got this message for ur line                                                                  "The method min(DoubleBinding,DoubleBinding) is undefined for the type Bindings"

Comment: @Isac You imported wrong `Bindings`. You need `javafx.beans.binding.Bindings`.

Comment: wow thats embarrassing, sorry for beeing so slow. Thanks for ur help :)